# Installing Phonegap on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Recently I was trying to install Cordova onto my mac so I can compile for the iphone, but I ran into a problem. The option to create a Cordova project wasn't there on xcode. I looked online and saw that I needed to create the project through the terminal. I did this, but nothing was created as far as I can see.

On the terminal, after dragging the bin folder to the terminal I did: ./create /desktop/ios-program/ com.appname appname

Did I do something wrong? Thanks

Comment: I tried using the cordova installer, like the adobe guide said, but no new project showed up in xcode!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a complete guide is given to create phonegap environment in xcode

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-xcode-for-ios.html

if it is not enough than go for this

http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/archive/11-12-27/setup_your_phonegap_development_environment_on_mac.aspx

Comment: I installed Cordova the way the first guide told me, but for some reason the option to make a cordova project isn't appearing on xcode...

Comment: I figured it out on my own, but your first guide was pretty helpful, so I'll give you best answer...

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Phonegap is installed but not appearing on xcode. Can you share the solution?

Comment: Love you brother u help me a lot.

Comment: @TahirMehmood it's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html

These instructions are pretty clear, even if the directory tree you get after extracting the zip file is not exactly the one they show.

After installing all the requirements:

```
1. extract the content of phonegap-2.7.0.zip wherever you want
2. go to lib/ios/bin and run the create command with the suggested parameters.
3. open the finder and go to the directory you used as first parameter
4. doubleclick the file with extension xcodeproj to open XCode and the project will be automatically created
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are inside \phonegap-2.7.0\lib\ios\bin before entering `./create` command. 
Refer the [Blog Tutorial](http://mythoughtsandexperiments.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-install-phonegap-in-mac-and.html)