# Unable to get the phone gap plugin

Tags: cordova, ios4, phonegap-plugins

I am new to both iOS, and phone gap. and i have been trying to get the feel of phone gap. 
I followed the URL

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-ios.html

But, @ runtime, clicking the button, gives the following error.

```
2012-08-01 12:30:13.403 myProjectName[2777:707] [INFO] report:deviceready
2012-08-01 12:30:20.397 myProjectName[2777:707] ERROR: Plugin 'com.tricedesigns.HelloPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-08-01 12:30:20.398 myProjectName[2777:707] FAILED pluginJSON = {"className":"com.tricedesigns.HelloPlugin","methodName":"nativeFunction","arguments":["com.tricedesigns.HelloPlugin2","success"]}
```

Kindly point out where am i missing?

Comment: check my answer to this similar query

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733575/installing-phonegap-on-ios/11734167#11734167

Answer (score 0):

The link you are referring is old. Take reference for iOS phonegap plugins from here
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/8d1ea688db4bdc6220b43fc92e492d8b76550736/iOS